# C++ Finding an incomplete string from a text file

Tags: c++, string

I have a program which reads text files and parses information from them, and I am trying to accomplish a task like this:

A text file which has about 500 characters of data in it, in this data lies user name like so:

```
this_just_some_random_data_in_the_file_hdfhehhr2342t543t3y3y
_please_don't_mind_about_me(username: "sara123452")reldgfhfh
2134242gt3gfd2342353ggf43t436tygrghrhtyj7i6789679jhkjhkuklll
```

The thing is that we **only need to find and write** `sara123452` to a string from that text file. The user name is unknown of course, and does not have fixed length.

Here is what I have managed to do so far:

```
std::string Profile = "http://something.com/all_users/data.txt";
std::string FileName = "profileInfo.txt";
std::string Buffer, ProfileName;
std::ifstream FileReader;

DeleteUrlCacheEntryA(Profile .c_str());
URLDownloadToFileA(0, Profile .c_str(), FileName.c_str(), 0, 0);

FileReader.open(FileName);
if (FileReader.is_open()) 
{
    std::ostringstream FileBuffer;
    FileBuffer << FileReader.rdbuf();
    Buffer= FileBuffer.str();
    if (Buffer.find("(username: ") != std::string::npos) {
       cout << "dont know how to continue" << endl;
    }
    FileReader.close();
    DeleteFileA(FileName.c_str());
}
else {
}
cin.get();
```

So how can I get the user name string and assign/copy it to `ProfileName` string?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Please can you include a question.

Comment: @destination-data cleared it up a bit in the end.

Comment: Is the username actually surrounded by quotes in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is something like the code below -- possibly with minor tweaks to account for the username being quoted. The key here is to remember that your Buffer variable is a std::string and you can use substring once you have a definite start and end.

```
std::size_t userNameStartIndex, userNameEndIndex

...

userNameStartIndex = Buffer.find("(username: ")) + 11;

if (userNameStartIndex != std::string::npos) {
   userNameEndIndex = Buffer.find(")", userNameStartIndex);

   if (userNameEndIndex != std::string::npos)
   {
       ProfileName = Buffer.substr(userNameStartIndex, userNameEndIndex - userNameStartIndex)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to do it, but this one would be less painful I guess.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Profile
{   // ...
    string name;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false); // optional

    // read from file
    string filename {"data1.txt"};
    ifstream in {filename};

    vector<Profile> profiles;
    // tweaks this pattern in case you're not happy with it
    regex pat {R"(\(username:\s*\"(.*?)\"\))"};

    for (string line; getline(in,line); ) {

        Profile p;
        sregex_iterator first(cbegin(line), cend(line), pat);
        const sregex_iterator last;

        while (first != last) {
            // By dereferencing a first, you get a smatch object.
            // [1] gives you the matched sub-string:
            p.name = (*first)[1]; // (*first)[1] = sara123452
            profiles.push_back(p);
            ++first;
        }
    }

    // Test
    for (const auto& p : profiles)
       cout << p.name << '\n';

}
```